# Link post to blog from a static page

Tags: posts, homepage, blog, blog-page

I'm a WP rookie, and I just designed a static homepage that shows the 3 most recent posts in my database. I would like to redirect the user to another page in order to show him the entire blog post everytime a post title gets clicked.

I already created my blog page using the reading settings menu but I can't figure out how to link each post to my blog page and show it's content on it. Any indications?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to WordPress! I'm going to assume you're creating your first theme. I would start by reading about The Loop http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop which is a crucial concept for WordPress themes.

If you designed your homepage within the WordPress admin by going to Pages, adding a new page, and putting your static homepage markup in the content body of the post then there is nothing you can do as dynamic logic using PHP is done in the theme of a site.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. No, I didn't create my home page via admin, just my blog page. I've used the loop before but in a simpler layout. What I want to do is something similar to this page: http://www.degordian.com/index/ as you can see there is a section with three entries, when you click one of those thumbnails you get another page with the post you selected. I'm currently using wp_get_recent_posts($args) to fetch my posts, I'll try the loop approach.